# Can't add fixed column types to tabularx columns with different widths

Tags: tables, tabularx

Trying to introduce a ratio between the `X`-column types of `tabularx` not 1:1.  I now encountered the problem that my third column type `p{11ex}` is no longer accepted.  I don't know why.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X}p{11ex}}
the quick brown fox jumped & over the lazy dog a few times to pad & out the sentence \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have braces that don't belong there. Remove the brace `{` before the first `>` and the `}` after the second `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you! What a small error...

The solution is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}Xp{11ex}}
the quick brown fox jumped & over the lazy dog a few times to pad & out the sentence \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Package tabu makes setting widths of X columns much easier.

```
\usepackage{tabu}
```

and

```
\begin{tabu}[X[2] X X]
```

Will make the first column twice as large, etc.